# How to build multi-target solution on .NET Core on Mac or linux?

Tags: linux, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

I have solution with multi-targeted csproj files:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net45;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm trying to build .NET Core part of this solution on Linux, but can't manage it. If I run

```
dotnet build
```

It builds all targets: `netcoreapp1.1`, `netstandard1.6` and `net45` and fails on the net45, because .NET Core does not provide .NET 4.5 platform on Linux. I tried to workaround this issue by specifying mono as a framework for building, but solution is complex and not all .NET 4.5 things are supported in mono. However this could help somebody else to avoid `can't find .NETFramework v4.5` just run:

```
FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/ dotnet restore
FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/ dotnet build
```

When I run `dotnet build /p:TargetFramework=netcoreapp1.1` I get alot of errors, I think because projects with `netstandard1.6` was not built.

If I pass

```
  dotnet build /p:TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp1.1\;netstandard1.6
```

I get

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: netstandard1.6
```

How can I pass `netcoreapp1.1` and `netstandard1.6` target frameworks simultaneously to msbuild from command line?

I know that I can add additional property and make conditional compilation depending on it, but I don't want to change csproj to make this workaround.

Comment: `dotnet build --help`  --> `-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>          Compile a specific framework` so use -f to select the framework e.g. `dotnet build -f netcoreapp1.0`

Comment: @Pawel this does not work I see the same errors as I build `dotnet build /p:TargetFramework=netcoreapp1.1`

Comment: Looks like you also need to specify the target runtime

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I think you should consider creating an issue at [the dotnet/CLI repo](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/).

Comment: @Set should I specify targetRuntime in command line or in csproj or both? I tried to add `/p:RuntimeIdentifiers=win-x86` into command line but this does not help too

Comment: if you have mono + mono msbuild installed, (latest 5.*), does it build using `msbuild /t:Restore` and `msbuild` ?

Comment: @MartinUllrich some projects can be build with these commands, but others needs to be adapting for mono or cannot be built at all. For example I can't build projects with `portable45-net45+win8` target even if `referenceassemblies-pcl` are installed.

Answer (score 7):

If you really don't want to even try building full framework or PCL versions on linux and just want a .net core app or .net standard library, you can modify the project file (`.csproj`) to only multi-target on windows and behave like a project targeting a single framework on non-windows like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  <TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This allows specifying `netstandard*` and `netcoreapp*` for non-windows individually for all projects and the .net core only versions of your app will be able to build using just plain `dotnet restore` / `dotnet build` commands.

Comment: I don't want to drop off ability to compile net45 target on linux forever, I just want to have the ability to build only .net core target. And also adding conditional compilation for target frameworks broke toolings (intellisence, unit testing etc) at least for the time the question was asked (I didn't check this now maybe something was fixed). These are two reasons why I asked for solution without conditional csproj.

Comment: This is currently how the .net core sdk components are built and tooling works as long as you conditionally set the plural `TargetFrameworks` property. if your solution does not build using mono (e.g. usage of components not using mono / PCL) and not with the reference assembly NuGet packages, there's no way to build without this condition. the condition can be on anything - doesn't have to be `$(OS)` but can be anything (e.g. so you can call `dotnet build /p:DropTheNetFx=true`).

Comment: What if project is targeted `net45` only? How conditionals can help to disable building of such projects on .net core?

Answer (score 4):

RefferenceAssembly package is now stable and all you have to do is to reference it after setting up all targets you need by running:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies --version 1.0.0
```

Or manually in your project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0">
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: I have just learned about this package. My understanding is that this will be okay for build but not for unit tests since there's no actual implementation of the types. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure mono is up-to-date and then paste this bit of boilerplate into your project.
I'm pretty confident this doesn't break the intellisense or tooling.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4')) and '$(OS)' == 'Unix'">
  <!-- When compiling .NET SDK 2.0 projects targeting .NET 4.x on Mono using 'dotnet build' you -->
  <!-- have to teach MSBuild where the Mono copy of the reference asssemblies is -->
  <!-- Look in the standard install locations -->
  <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND EXISTS('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono')">/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
  <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND EXISTS('/usr/lib/mono')">/usr/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
  <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND EXISTS('/usr/local/lib/mono')">/usr/local/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
  <!-- If we found Mono reference assemblies, then use them -->
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.0-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471'">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
  <EnableFrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">true</EnableFrameworkPathOverride>
  <!-- Add the Facades directory.  Not sure how else to do this. Necessary at least for .NET 4.5 -->
  <AssemblySearchPaths Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">$(FrameworkPathOverride)/Facades;$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```

From https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2312/multi-targetting-net-framework-and-net-core-in-a-single-project / https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335#issuecomment-368669050

Comment: I found it really useful to take the answer above, wrap in `<Project></Project>`, and store as `MonoForFramework.targets` in my repo, referencing from other .csproj files with:

`<Project Import="..\MonoForFramework.targets" />`

Comment: Typo in daf's suggestion: `<Import Project="..." />` _not_ `<Project Import ...` . Also don't forget the <?xml declaration